# Where should I make changes in the code to solve the error in Pine script v5 for tradingview

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am using this code to plot a horizontal line from 9:42 AM candle close each day in tradinview Pinescript verson 5 but getting errors...please help :(

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jghQO.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXHf0.png)`your text`

Comment: please edit your question and replace the images by the code (or error message) itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'end' at the end of a for block in pinescript.
Delete the line 17 with 'end', this error will disappear.